# Is it possible pinging with C# like in the CMD?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to get IP address of a dns server with the code:

```
var address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(domain)[0];
```

Its working on my pc, but when I'm doing it through someone else pc its giving him different result (IPv6 instead of IPv4).
I did try to use the method

```
var ipV4Address = address.MapToIPv4();
```

but that just returning the wrong IP address

p.s: btw, when using the command ping dns.address.blabla on both computers the result is the same.

Comment: Why do you think the result is wrong? And what do you need, by the way? The remote IP address or a ping answer (test whether the remote is available)?

Comment: see how it returns an array? check the other entries....

Comment: or at least query the addresses for the ip4 one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the domain have IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, you'll get both. Filter by `AddressFamily` to `InterNetwork` only (IPv4) instead of `InterNetworkV6` (IPv6)

```
var ipV4Address = Dns.GetHostAddresses(domain)
                     .First(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question in the header: Yes, it is. Here's an outline of how to do that:

```
        using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
        ...
        private static bool PingWithResponse(int timeout, string iP, out string response)
        {
            bool result = false;

            using (var p = new Ping())
            {
                var r = p.Send(iP, timeout);

                response = $"Ping to {iP} [{r.Address}]";

                if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    response += $" Successful Response delay = {r.RoundtripTime} ms";
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    response += $" Failed Status: {r.Status}";
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```